# Schreibung und Aussprache von Ortsnamen

Tags: pronunciation

Eine Frage, die mich immer mal wieder beschäftigt, ist, warum manche Ortsnamen im deutschsprachigen Raum anders ausgesprochen werden als sie geschrieben werden?

Ein Beispiel wäre "Oer-Erkenschwick" (meines Wissens **nicht** ausgesprochen Ör-Erkenschwick) und im Gegensatz dazu der Ortsname "Voerde" (ausgesprochen "Vörde").

Gibt es eine Regel, die bestimmte Aussprachen für Ortsnamen festlegt, oder haben diese sich nur eingebürgert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Für die Aussprache bzw. Schreibung von Eigennamen (nicht nur Ortsnamen, sondern beispielsweise auch Familiennamen) gibt es keine festen Regeln. Die Schreibweisen sind zu sehr unterschiedlichen Zeiten fixiert worden, größtenteils vor der Normierung der deutschen Rechtschreibung, und unterlagen den Moden der jeweiligen Zeit; Beispiele für solche Moden wären Konsonantenhäufung (*Burckhardt*), th-Schreibung (*Fürth*) oder c-Schreibung, wobei diese allerdings meistens wieder rückgängig gemacht wurde (*Cassel*, *Neu-Cölln*; noch aktuell: *Cottbus*, aber *Kottbusser Tor* in Berlin). Regionale Unterschiede spielen auch eine große Rolle, in einigen Gegenden wurde ein stummes *e* als Längenzeichen verwendet, wie in *Oer* oder *Soest*.

Kurz gesagt: Man muß es wissen oder nachschlagen (in einem Aussprachewörterbuch). Auch professionelle Sprecher liegen oft zumindest bei der Betonung daneben; es heißt z.B. Saarbr**ü**cken, aber Zw**ei**brücken, Wilhelmsh**a**ven, aber W**i**lhelmsburg, K**a**rlsruhe, aber Karlsh**o**rst, Salzg**i**tter, aber S**a**lzwedel.

Comment: Als aktuelles Beispiel (und daher eventuell besser nachvollziehbares Beispiel) möchte ich noch *Schloß Holte-Stukenbrock* ergänzen, dass nach heutigen Rechtschreibregeln gleich zwei Fehler (drei, wenn das c in *brock* ein Dehnungs-c) enthält und eigentlich *Schloss-Holte-Stukenbrock* geschrieben werden müsste.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Der Fall des Bindestrichs ist, glaube ich, nicht amtlich geregelt. Die übliche Schreibung für zusammengesetzte Namen, von denen mindestens einer aus mehreren Teilen besteht, ist aber nur _ein_ Bindestrich, und zwar an der Fuge: _Herr Müller-von Mainhausen_, _Kassel-Bad Wilhelmshöhe_ oder eben _Schloß Holte-Stukenbrock_.

Comment: _Sassnitz_ (vormals _Saßnitz_) hat nach der Rechtschreibreform seinen Namen bzw. dessen Schreibung angepaßt. _Esslingen_ ist automatisch richtig geworden, nachdem es zuvor hundert Jahre "falsch" (oder seiner Zeit voraus) war. _Neuss_ ist so "falsch" wie eh und je.

Comment: §50: »Man setzt einen Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, deren erste Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen.« Als Beispiel wird u. a. die Van-Gogh-Ausstellung genannt. Für reine Eigennamen gilt natürlich eine gewisse Narrenfreiheit, ich finde es dennoch scheußlich und es veleitet mich dazu, Texte falsch zu lesen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Keines der Beispiele in § 50 ist einschlägig. Es sind alles Zusammensetzungen "aus einem Grundwort und mehreren Bestimmungswörtern", wie es in den Duden-Regeln zur alten Rechtschreibung hieß. Daß eine fiktive Kassel-Bad-Wilhelmshöhe-Gesellschaft, die jährlich eine Adalbert-Müller-von-Mainhausen-Medaille verleiht für Verdienste um die Schloß-Holte-Stukenbrock-Partnerschaft, ein paar Bindestriche mehr bräuchte, ist unstrittig.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Sehr haarspalterisch könnte man auch argumentieren, daß diese Fälle schon vom Wortlaut nicht eingeschlossen sind, weil nicht nur die _ersten_ Bestandteile Eigennamen sind (sondern auch der letzte). Eigentlich ist es ein Fall für § 46, der nicht von Bindestrichen zwischen _allen_ Bestandteilen spricht (aber auch nur unpassende Beispiele aufführt).

Comment: Wenn etwas in (durchdachten) Regeln nicht explizit ausgeschlossen ist, ist es eingeschlossen (anderenfalls kann ich fast alles hineininterpretieren). § 50 fordert **vom Wortlaut her** also klar einen Bindestrich zwischen *Schloß* und *Holte.* Den Beispielen nach zu urteilen haben die Schreiber der Regeln hier gepatzt und wollten diesen Fall hier nicht abdecken (und auch nirgendwo sonst). Geist und Grundparadigmata der Regeln wiederum wären ohne Bindestrich m. E. verletzt, da *Holte* stärker an *Stukenbrock* gebunden wäre als an *Schloß* (vgl. *Mehr-Kornbrot* und § 44).

Comment: Sassnitz’ Namensänderung hat nebenbei anscheinend nichts mit der Rechtschreibreform zu tun. Siehe u. a. [hier](http://nachrichtenbrett.de/v/Eintrag.php?threadid=341&boardid=1).

Comment: @chirlu: Neuss schreibt sich nicht "seit eh und je" mit ss, sondern erst seit Ende der Sechziger. Damit wollte man wohl den internationalen Firmen entgegenkommen, die dort häufig ihre "Düsseldorfer" Niederlassung haben.